# How SELECT different options AS value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join

I'm trying to populate storage table with sql. There are two two types of storage items, products and cols. Products consist of cols and have table 'prodcols' for linking.

I have:

```
Orderlines
- productID
- orderQTY

ProdCols
- productID
- colID
- colQTY

Storage
- itemID (can be productID or colID)
- itemType (Product or Col)
- itemName
- itemQTY
```

Needed result:

```
itemType | itemID | itemName | itemQTY | itemOrderQTY | itemFreeQTY
Product  | 1001   | *name*   | 50      | 20           | 30
Col      | C101   | *name*   | 80      | 60           | 20


     SUM of orderQTYs (of each productID) AS itemOrderQTY
     itemQTY - itemOrderQTY AS itemFreeQTY

     itemQTY is maintained by other parts of software
```

I have achieved a way to list either products or cols with needed qtys but don't know how to list them both with single clause. End result includes a few WHERE with variables to quickly narrow the results, itemName for example.

My Attempt for cols, works but is slow:

```
    (SELECT ProdCols.ColQTY*(SELECT SUM(OrderQTY)FROM Orderlines WHERE productID
 IN (SELECT ProductID FROM ProdCols WHERE ProdCols.ColID=storage.itemID) AND ..)
 AS itemOrderQTY 
FROM Storage, Orderlines, ProdCols 
GROUP BY Storage.Itemid, Storage.type, Storage.name, Storage.qty..
```

For products this works ok:

```
(SELECT SUM(orderlines.orderQTY) FROM orderlines 
    WHERE orderlines.productID=storage.itemID AND ...) AS itemOrderQTY
    FROM storage, orderlines
    GROUP BY storage.itemID,storage.itemType,storage.itemName, storage.ItemQTY
```

Is there a way to UNION these two? Why is the one for cols performing very slow?

I'm running ms sql server express with custom platform.

ps. sorry for bad naming for question, just couldn't come up with better one..

Comment: Well if you know how to do each, can you use a union combine each and then `insert into table select A union B`?  W/o your SQL i'm a bit lost on what you're trying to do.  It looks like you need to join prodcols to storage once for productID and one for colId with prodID and colID always having one value or the other null.  If so a union seems to be the way to go here or a conditional `or join`... but I think the union is cleaner/easier to maintain.

Comment: Everything else should be just select but for 'itemOrderQTY' I need to select SUM(qty) for either productID or find out what pID's use certain colID and SUM qty of those.
The way I got it working was also very slow to perform so it probably has something wrong..

Comment: edit the question w/ your attempt.  easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

```
Select S.ItemName, S.itemQty, p.ProductId, p1.ColId, p1.ColQty, 
    Sum(o.OrderQty) over(partition by p.ProductId) as ItemOrderQty,
    S.ItemQty - Sum(o.OrderQty) over(partition by p.ProductId) as ItemFreeQty   
from Storage s
left join ProdCols p
    on s.ItemId = P.ProductID
    and s.itemType = 'Product'
left join ProdCols P1
    on s.ItemId = P.ColId
    and s.itemType = 'Col'
left join OrderLines o
    on p.ProductId = o.ProductId
```

You might required to change to inner join for some of the tables based on your requirement

Comment: I don't think so since the expected results have product and col types in different rows. this would put them in the same wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't exactly understand how these over / partition things work but I will try it tomorrow, thanks.